# How to design the Vkontakte share button to look like the facebook one?

Tags: html, css, vk

[Vkontakte](http://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=Sharing_External_Pages), the russian social network, has api for adding share/like button to my website.

Does anyone knows how I can show the counter bubble even if its '0'? How can i show the bubble above/below the button like facebook, twitter, and google plus can?

Comment: @Hast, why did you add a new tag for Vkontakte when there is already a tag for it?  All of the questions you added the tag to *already* have the proper tag.

Comment: @Charles because the social network is not already called vkontakte and this name is deprecated now. I added the new tag to a few question to let new questioners choose the right one. It would be nice to make a synonym or even remove old 'vkontakte' tag, but I have no rights and I guess nobody else will do this. Or if you can advice me how can I do that, please, tell me.

Comment: @Hast You should post over on Meta about this then.

Comment: @Charles see Meta discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185546/vkontakte-tag-should-be-renamed-or-becase-a-synonym).

Comment: Are you guys serious? You do not have anything better to do than argue over tags? Why not try to really help out by trying to find a solution? and btw, VK is Vkontakte. It is pronounced Vkontakte, and written Vkontakte, same way that Facebook is FB... but FB can be anything else...   Can you at least try to find a solution to the problem at hand? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Like Widget](http://vk.com/dev/Like). Layout "Mini button with counter at the top" is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but one of the issues with the out of the box button from this tool is that the counter bubble does not show up if the counter is 0. I am interested in forcing it to show up. Thanks

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul, did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @SimpleGuy sorry mate, it has been 5 years ago, back then I did find something, but cannot remember that change now. Sorry.